# Запрос удаления по значению checkbox

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

Запрос удаления по значению `checkbox` - почему не удаляет? И как выдать сообщение, если не выбрали `box`

```
    echo "<table class='ram'><td>фио преп<td>должность
            <td>степень<td>контакт<td><form action=' ' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='delteacher' 
            value='Удалить выбранное'>";
        $t=("SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`");
    $q=mysql_query($t)or die(mysql_error());  
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

            do
            {
            echo  "<tr><td>".$r['фио преподавателя']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$r['должность' ]."</td>";
            echo  "<td>".$r['степень']."</td>";
            echo  "<td>".$r['контакт преподавателя']."</td>".
            "<td>";
            ?><input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' 
            value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">

            <?
            if(isset($_POST['delteacher']))
{

    foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value)
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='{$value}'");
   }
}

            }
            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q));
            echo "</table></form>";

        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если вывести на экран текст запроса:

```
DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='{$value}'
```

Что там будет?

Comment: чего то ничего не получается вывести

foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value)
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='{$value}'");

echo $value;
   }

Comment: Если ничего не выводит, значит там ничего нет.
Оттого и не удаляет. Напишите вместо $value {$r['фио преподавателя']}. Удалит?

Comment: хорошее чувство юмора при  одном выделеном боксе  удалил все поля...)))
исправить бы)

Comment: if(isset($_POST['delteacher']))
{
$i=0
while(??????){
foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value)  
echo $value;

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE
 `фио преподавателя`='{$r['фио преподавателя']}'");
 echo $r['фио преподавателя'];
          }
Как же правильно прописать : пока передаются значения на удаление